# Java Swing JTextField setInputVerifier keep focus on TextField

Tags: java, swing, inputverifier

I have a `public class JdbDateTextField extends JTextField` and in the constructor I add `this.setInputVerifier(new ValidDateOrEmptyVerifier());`.

I use `class ValidDateOrEmptyVerifier extends InputVerifier` to verify the format of the input.

If the input is in the wrong format and the user looses the focus of the `JdbDateTextField`, I return `false` in the `ValidDateOrEmptyVerifier` and the focus is gained again to the `JdbDateTextField` again.

This works if the user switches from the `JdbDateTextField` to another textField or presses a Button. If pressing a button and the format of the input in the  is wrong then no action for the button is performed and the focus is still at the `JdbDateTextField`.

This is exactly what I want. The user can not leave the `JdbDateTextField`  until he enters a valid string.

The problem is that the `JdbDateTextField` is in a JPanel which is in a `JTabbedPane` so I have a GUI with several tabs.

If I have the `JdbDateTextField` selected, enter a invalid input and then directly click on another tab it still switches the tab. So I was able to provide a wrong input.

My Question is:

Is there a way to perform an Input Verification which does not allow to execute any other event before it is `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution I can think of is to assign the JTabbedPane a custom selection model which refuses to allow changing tabs unless the current InputVerifier succeeds:

```
int index = tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();

tabbedPane.setModel(new DefaultSingleSelectionModel() {
    @Override
    public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
        Component focusOwner =
            FocusManager.getCurrentManager().getFocusOwner();

        if (focusOwner instanceof JComponent) {
            JComponent c = (JComponent) focusOwner;
            InputVerifier verifier = c.getInputVerifier();
            if (verifier != null && !verifier.shouldYieldFocus(c)) {
                return;
            }
        }

        super.setSelectedIndex(index);
    }
});

tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I can do this as an answer:

The solution above works for the `JTabbedPane`

But I can still select other GUI elements.

My Application is build like this:
[image]

For every `Person ID` I show other `Birthdate` values in the `JTabbedPane`
and I can still switch to another `Person ID` if the `ValidDateOrEmptyVerifier` returns `false`.

So is there a way to disallow all events in the Main Frame until the `ValidDateOrEmptyVerifier` returns `true`.

So Basically what I want is that the user can only exit the `"Birthdate" JdbDateTextField` if he enters a valid Date or the field is empty.